# OP will not respect change of tags

Tags: discussion, tags, rollbacks

There is a poorly written question, where after civilly asking for clarification, was never really fixed and the OP became somewhat belligerent.  The only thing I could do was to flag it as a "low quality" question and then re-title and add specific tags so that it would become just a little more useful for the reader.

The OP seems to want this question to remain vague as he's changed the tags back twice.

I certainly don't want to bother the Mods but the issue of the tags getting rolled back only came up after I already flagged it.  Naturally I cannot flag it again for this new issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132723/jqueryui-draggable-problem-jsfiddle-included

More generally, how do we handle such situations where the OP does not want more specific tags added where his are too general?  Just flag it?

Thank-you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't get into an edit war. It never ends well. Fix the tags, and if the OP rolls your edits back, just walk away.

There's nothing really a mod can do other than a) re-tagging, and writing a stern comment not to change them back, or b) locking the question against further modification. Mods won't generally do either, rightfully so, unless the circumstances are extreme (tagging with completely random or profane/abusive tags, for instance).

Comment: The same applies to the comments on that question, IMO. Don't get into a p*ssing match, however tempting. It drags everybody down. I don't always take my own advice, but I should.

Comment: That's a shame... I've been having a bad time at Stackoverflow today... several times only trying to help people and things going bad.  One expects people looking for help to behave more civilly towards would-be helpers.  Your advice is sound.

Comment: Yes- I'm learning to keep my responses very on-topic and just flag the sarcastic or chatty replies.